# Updating ubuntu-core snappy without internet connection

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

How the ubuntu-core package can be updated without connection to the store?

Can I download the ubuntu-core package as *.snap file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any snap, you can directly download them unauthenticated from the store (this is what `sudo snap install ubuntu-core` does). https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppStore/Interfaces/ClickPackageIndex#Snap-specific_endpoints should be a start if you don't want to use the command line to get access to it. Come on #snappy on freenode, some store guy should be able to give you the exact details on how to retrieve those snaps.